# yii2 double gridview in a form

Tags: php, gridview, yii2

I have 2 gridview in a form and from them I have to extract selectedrows, which I did with `'class' => 'kartik\grid\CheckboxColumn'`.
In a controller receive the selected values in a `selection[]` variable.

Here comes the problem. The `selection[]` variable brings the selection of the 2 gridViews. Ex:

> array (size=2)
> 0 => string '10' (length=2)
> 1 => string '44' (length=2)

That result is the selection of one row of each GridView.
How can I separate the `selection[]` results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make your own column

```
[
    'header'=>Html::checkbox('selection_all', false, ['class'=>'select-all', 'value'=>1, 'onclick'=>'$(".custom-row-checkbox").prop("checked", $(this).is(":checked"));']),
    'contentOptions'=>['class'=>'custom-row-select'],
    'content'=>function($model, $key){
        return Html::checkbox('selection2[]', false, ['class'=>'custom-row-checkbox', 'value'=>$key]);
    },
    'hAlign'=>'center',
    'vAlign'=>'middle',
    ...
]
```

Comment: Great Solution, Thanks.